# Sorting a list of dates in string format

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have some lists of string elements which look like this:

```
{ Week 2.2012, Week 45.2014, Week 12.2011, ...}
{ Half 1.2013, Half 2.2015, Half 1.2010 ...}
{ Quarter 3.2005, Quarter 4.2010, Quarter 2.2011, ...}
```

Knowing that these string values cannot be parsed as DateTime (?), how can I sort the lists?

Expected result:

```
{ Week 12.2011, Week 2.2012, Week 45.2014, ...}
{ Half 1.2010, Half 1.2013, Half 2.2015, ...}
{ Quarter 3.2005, Quarter 4.2010, Quarter 2.2011, ...}
```

Comment: What would sorted list look like?

Comment: Something like these: { Week 12.2011, Week 2.2012, Week 45.2014, ...}, { Half 1.2010, Half 1.2013, Half 2.2015,  ...}, { Quarter 3.2005, Quarter 4.2010, Quarter 2.2011, ...}

Comment: So the sorting is _per list_, they are never combined?  Make that clear(er) in the question. Also add the expected output there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an implementation of IComparer using your custom logic and pass it to the List.Sort method.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution i'd like to create a datestring parser which returns date. Next step you could use sorting list of Tuple by datetime.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34201701/3970411) said you can sort these data by using linq:

```
var sorted = list.Select(x => x.Split(' ', '.'))
    .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x[2])).ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x[1]))
    .Select(x => $"{x[0]} {x[1]}.{x[2]}") //or string.Format("{0} {1}.{2}", x[0], x[1], x[2])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I parse both of them to ensure the format is correct. @Sinatr

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like these strings **can** be parsed as `DateTime`.

As far as I can understand:

`Week 2.2012` is "Second week of 2012" = 15 January 2012

`Half 2.2015` is "Six months of 2015" = 1 July 2015 (not quite sure with "half" though - it can have slightly different meaning)

`Quarter 3.2005` is "Third quarter of 2005" = 1 October 2005

and so on.

So you can parse these values, convert them to `DateTime` and sort the lists.